# R How to use dynamic scoping into a lapply job

Tags: r, scope, lapply

Im creating a function that needs an object not defined to produce a plot. Because I want to keep the function clean without many arguments, I thought to use dynamic scoping. I have a problem when the needed object is created into a lapply function.

With the first situation, the function **f** needs the object **text**, and both are created into the lapply function. It's working as expected.

```
attach(mtcars)

lapply(seq(2), function(x) {

  text = paste0('Title-', x)
  f = function( ) { plot(wt, mpg, main = text, pch = 20) }
  return(f())

})
```

But if the function **f** is created previously, **text** is not found. I expected the function would find **text** created into the lapply function

```
f = function( ) { plot(wt, mpg, main = text, pch = 20) }

lapply(seq(2), function(x) {

  text = paste0('Title-', x)
  return(f())

})
```

How can I reuse the function **f** previously created with variables created into a lapply function?
Maybe <<- assigment is a solution but it's not recommended. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to pass arguments to `f` function? Usually `f` would take `text` as argument which can be changed through `lapply`.

Comment: Yes. That's my workflow. But when f function is really big, it needs a lot of arguments, and I thought using non-defined objects would be a cleaner way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specifically look for `text` in the calling frame:

```r
f <- function() plot(wt, mpg, main = get("text", envir = parent.frame()), pch = 20)

lapply(seq(2), function(x) {
  text = paste0('Title-', x)
  return(f())
})
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's working. I thought when scoping were looking to the lapply environment automatically

Comment: It surprised me a bit too @Archymedes.